# What is the fastest way to setup a server purely to serve a single JavaScript that writes to a local file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, nginx, server

Right now I have a single JavaScript file on a web server that creates a new file every time the JavaScript is run. I'm moving this to its own server to make certain the file loads as fast as possible. A second server reads these files, processes them (writes necessary information to a table) and cleans up after itself.

How would you setup a server to accomplish this simple task?

Here's a picture of what I'm after:

1. Remote page view (on another website)
2. Pave view triggers JavaScript on my server (`Server Alpha`)
3. JavaScript writes to a file (currently through AJAX using PHP on a server running Apache, but open to alternatives)
4. An auxiliary server (`Server Beta`) reads all new files, writes to database, and removes processed files from `Server Alpha`

Goals:

1. Handle maximum concurrent connections
2. Minimize JavaScript load time
3. Limited dependency on other services

Comment: I'm not sure I would change my server if I were you. Set your cache content headers and route your web traffic through a CDN. If done correctly, very few users will ever fetch the file from your server again.

Comment: Unfortunately the current server has hit max load at times and slowed down JavaScript response. You're saying a CDN would fix that?